# CakePHP not displaying some value from database properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cakephp

A bit of background, I am working upon an already existing system that is made by someone else. With little knowledge and experience of CakePHP, I have to add functionalities to it. Now here's my problem.

I have a list of "cards" with each containing a row of data from the database. The card itself displays minimal information but there is an edit button that shows a modal where the user can edit the values. Upon opening the modal, the input fields are supposedly already filled with the corresponding data from the specific card.

I don't know what did I do wrong, but the first 3 values values (id, invoice_status, service_id) that are displayed do not belong to the correct row, and instead it always belong to the first row in the database.

Below are my codes

**view.ctp**

```
// List of item cards
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-xl-4"
       style="margin-left: 60%; float:right;">
      <?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" ><i class="flaticon2-plus"></i>Add Project Item</span>',
          array('type' => 'button'), ['escape' => false, 'data-target' => '#kt_modal_6projectitem', 'data-toggle' => 'modal'])
      ?>

  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-12" data-scroll="true" data-height="700"
       style="height: 700px; overflow: hidden; ">

      <div
          class="kt-timeline-v1 kt-timeline-v1--justified"
          style="margin-left:5%;">
          <?php if (!empty($client->client_projects)): ?>
              <?php foreach (array_reverse($client->client_projects) as $clientProjects): ?>

                  <div class="kt-timeline-v1__items"
                       style="margin-bottom: -5%;">
                      <div class="kt-timeline-v1__marker"></div>
                      <div class="kt-timeline-v1__item kt-timeline-v1__item--first">
                          <div class="kt-timeline-v1__item-circle">
                              <div class="kt-bg-danger"></div>
                          </div>
                          <span class=" kt-font-brand"></span>

                          <div
                              class="kt-timeline-v1__item-content"
                              style="max-width: 90%;">
                              <div class="kt-timeline-v1__item-title ">
                                  <div style="float: right; ">
                                      <button
                                          class="editProjectItem btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-sm"
                                          data-projectItem-id="<?php echo $clientProjects->id ?>"
                                          data-projectItem-serviceid = "<?php echo $clientProjects->service_id ?>"
                                          data-projectItem-price = "<?php echo $clientProjects->price ?>"
                                          data-projectItem-progress = "<?php echo $clientProjects->progress ?>"
                                          data-projectItem-invoiceStatus="<?php echo $clientProjects->invoice_status ?>">
                                          <i class="flaticon2-note"
                                             data-toggle="kt-popover"
                                             data-content="Change Invoice Status"
                                             data-placement='bottom'></i>
                                      </button>

                                      <?= $this->Html->link('<span class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-sm"><i class="flaticon2-delete"></i></span>', ['controller' => 'ClientProjects', 'action' => 'delete', $clientProjects->id], ['escape' => false, 'data-toggle' => "kt-popover", 'data-content' => "delete Project Item", 'data-placement' => 'bottom', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you wish to delete this recipe?']) ?>

                                  </div>

                              </div>

                              <div
                                  class="kt-timeline-v1__item-body "
                                  style="word-wrap:break-word;">
                                  <p>
                                      Service: <?php echo $clientProjects->service_id; ?> <br>
                                      Price: $<?php echo $clientProjects->price; ?> <br>
                                      <?=  nl2br(h($clientProjects->invoice_status)) ?>
                                  </p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                  </div>

              <?php endforeach; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



// Edit item modal
<div class="modal-body">
                <span>
                    <?php ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['type' => 'post', 'patch', 'put', 'id' => 'editClientProjectForm', 'url' => [
                        'controller' => 'ClientProjects',
                        'action' => 'edit/'
                    ]]) ?>
                    <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('id', ['value' => $clientProjects->id, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->control('invoice_status', ['class' => 'form-control', 'value' => $clientProjects->invoice_status, 'empty' => '--select--', 'options' => array('' => '', 'Half-invoiced' => 'Half-invoiced', 'Half-paid' => 'Half-paid','Final-invoiced' => 'Final-invoiced', 'Final-paid' => 'Final-paid')]); ?>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->control('service_id', ['class' => 'form-control', 'value' => $clientProjects->service_id, 'type' => 'textarea']); ?>
                                        <div
                                            class="kt-input-icon">
                                            <span class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span></span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->control('price', ['class' => 'form-control', 'value' => $clientProjects->price, 'type' => 'textarea', 'placeholder' => '$']); ?>
                                        <div
                                            class="kt-input-icon">
                                            <span
                                                class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span></span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->control('progress', ['class' => 'form-control', 'value' => $clientProjects->progress, 'type' => 'textarea']); ?>
                                        <div
                                            class="kt-input-icon">
                                            <span
                                                class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span></span></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                            <?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
                            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
                            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Cancel',
                                array(
                                    'type' => 'button'),
                                array('class' => 'btn btn-secondary', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal',))
                            ?>
                        </div>

                                            </span>
</div>



// Edit item modal script
<script>
  $(document).on("click", ".editProjectItem", function () {

      var projectItemId = $(this).attr("data-projectItem-id");
      var service_id = $(this).attr("data-projectItem-serviceId");
      var price = $(this).attr("data-projectItem-price");
      var progress = $(this).attr("data-projectItem-progress");
      var invoice_status = $(this).attr("data-projectItem-invoiceStatus");

      //Half-invoiced' => 'Half-invoiced', 'Half-paid' => 'Half-paid','Final-invoiced' => 'Final-invoiced', 'Final-paid' => 'Final-paid'

      $('#id').val(projectItemId);
      if (invoice_status == "Half-invoiced") {
          $('#invoice_status option[value=Half-invoiced]').prop('selected', true);
      } else if (invoice_status == "Half-paid" || invoice_status == "Half-paid"){
          $('#invoice_status option[value=Half-paid]').prop('selected', true);
      } else if (invoice_status == "Final-invoiced" || invoice_status == "Final-invoiced"){
          $('#invoice_status option[value=Final-invoiced]').prop('selected', true);
      } else if (invoice_status == "Final-paid" || invoice_status == "Final-paid"){
          $('#invoice_status option[value=Final-paid]').prop('selected', true);
      };



      $('#service_id').val(service_id);
      $('#price').attr('value', price);
      $('#progress').attr('value', progress);

      $('#editClientProject').modal('show');
      $('#editClientProjectForm').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var form = $(this);
          $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo $this->Url->build([
                  'controller' => 'ClientProjects',
                  'action' => 'edit'
              ])?>' + '/' + projectItemId,
              type:'POST',
              data:form.serialize(),
              success: function(){
                  window.location.reload();
              }


          });

      })
  })


</script>
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function view($id = null)
  {

      $user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');
      $user_role=$this->Auth->user('role');
      $user_name=$this->Auth->user('username');


      $this->set("user_name", $user_name);
      $this->set("user_role", $user_role);


      $client = $this->Clients->get($id, [
          'contain' => [ 'Activities', 'Emails', 'Phones', 'Projects', 'ClientNotes', 'ClientProjects']
      ]);

      $this->set('client', $client);
      $this->set('id', $id);
      $this->loadModel('Activities');
      $this->loadModel('ClientNotes');
      $this->loadModel('ClientProjects');

      $activity = $this->Activities->newEntity();
      $clientNote = $this->ClientNotes->newEntity();
      $clientProject = $this->ClientProjects->newEntity();


      $this->loadModel('Projects');
      $this->loadModel('Talents');
      $client_talent = $this->Clients->get($id, [
          'contain' => [ 'Activities', 'Emails', 'Phones', 'Projects'=>['Talents'],'ClientNotes', 'ClientProjects']
      ]);
      //    var_dump($client_talent['projects'][0]['talents']);
      $this->set('client_talent',$client_talent['projects']);

      if($this->request->is('post')) {

          $clientProject = $this->ClientProjects->patchEntity($clientProject, $this->request->getData());
          $clientProject->client_id = $id;
          $clientProject->progress = 'Potential';

          if ($this->ClientProjects->save($clientProject)) {
              $this->Flash->success(__('The project item has been added.'));;
              return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);
          }
      }
      $this->set('clientProject', $clientProject);
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I am new to this forum and CakePHP and I really appreciate any help that you give me. If there are any other parts of code that I need to show as well or my me explanation is not clear, please do tell me. Thank you once again for your help

Comment: How much do you know about PHP, HTML and JavaScript/jQuery in general?

Comment: I really don't know much about CakePHP, especially the syntax that it uses in the controller, but I'm pretty ok with normal PHP. I would say I'm pretty ok with Javascript and I can look for JS and JQuery documentation. HTML, basic knowledge I would say

Comment: Okay, so it seems that the form (just one form for everything) is being built and populated initially with values from the first record (because it goes through them in reverse order, so the first is last, and that's the entity you have left when the form is made). The JavaScript attempts to set the values based on data attributes in the button that was clicked. Make use of `console.log` to see if it's retrieving those values correctly, and look at the generated form HTML to make sure that the IDs of the controls are what the `click` handler is expecting them to be when it writes to them.

Comment: In short, there's nothing specific about CakePHP that's breaking this, it's just a matter of making sure that the HTML and the JavaScript are "wired up" correctly.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I'll try and check it again, but what I don't understand is that the price and progress are shown correctly while the others aren't.

Comment: Well, price and progress are being set with the `attr` function, while others are using `val`. Certainly seems like either one should work, but...